# How can I merge a directory from a branch into another with a different project structure?

Tags: git

I have two branches: `branchX` and `branchY`. As you can see from the following trees they have a different structure:

```
branchX_root
└── app
```

```
branchY_root
├── dir1
│   ├── ...
└── dir2
    └── app
```

When I make changes in `branchY`, inside the `app` folder, I would like to have a git command to merge this folder inside `branchX`. The only solution I have at the moment is to copy and paste the folder manually.

(I know it is not a good thing to have two different structures but at the moment I have to deal with this.)

Comment: Are both branches long running branches which will never be killed, or will one of them be merged into the other?

Comment: branchX is for production, branchY is a staging branch so I use the latter to test the code and when I'm sure it works I deploy it on branchX. They will never be killed.

Comment: Could you elaborate, Alberto, please, one more time, what you're trying to achieve? If I correctly understood you for this moment, you could use the command `mv` for this folder.

Comment: Pratically, looking at `branchY_root`: `dir2` "represents" `branchX_root`. To update `branchX` I have to merge `\dir2\app` from `branchY` into `branchX`. However, I cannot do a simple merge, otherwise `dir1` would also be created on `branchX`.

Comment: So you don't want the folder to end up in another branch during the merge, am I right?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "end up". Anyway what I am interested in is updating the `app` folder of `branchX` with the `app` folder of `branchY`. This is a process that I will have to do periodically so the two branches will always be active. 

I update the code in the `app` folder of `branchY`, make sure it is working (**testing**), and finally update the `app` folder of `branchX` (**deployment**).